# Do I need a full Arduino board hardwired to a sensor to send data via Wi-Fi?

Tags: wifi, communication

Basically I want to wire a Wheatstone bridge style load-cell into a moving trolley and transmit the data to a remote workstation so I can get real-time feedback about the loading conditions.

Do I need to have a full board riding on the trolley that is wired in between the Wi-Fi transmitter and the bridge amplifier or is there a way that the current variations from the bridge can be read directly by the Wi-Fi transmitter and relayed to the remote in some translatable format?

The trolley design is extremely streamlined and it would be a bummer to have to add more than minimal electronics to make this happen...

Comment: the ESP8266 has the same kind of IO as an UNO, more or less, it's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are small packages out there with built in WiFi.  Node MCU is one of them, however its analog to digital conversion isn't up to the task of measuring bridges.  If you go that route you'll need to add a ADC to the Node MCU which will increase the total package size.